# NSWorkspace iconForFile: returns image of low quality

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder

I'm using `iconForFile:` selector of `NSWorkspace` class, but it returns an image of low quality.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? Is there any switch or flag to tell the framework to return an image in a different format?

Answer (score 6):

The docs state the returned icon's size is 32x32, but you can use `-[NSImage setSize:]` and it may load a larger representation:

```
NSImage * iconImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:file];
[iconImage setSize:NSMakeSize(128, 128)];
```

You can also use Icon Services (e.g. `GetIconRefFromFileInfo`) or QuickLook (e.g. `QLThumbnailImageCreate`) for a file's icon or preview icon at a larger size.

Comment: I can't find override of that function with parameter setSize. Can you point me please to correct documentation? (I was looking at NSWorkspace header)

Comment: Also, by your opinion, do you think that Icon Services are good place for searching support for icon-overlay in finder?

Comment: @user2381688 sorry that is `-[NSImage setSize:]` -- updated answer. I still use Icon Services. Just avoid the deprecated stuff.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try Icon Services api and resize of image. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: @user2381688 ok - try `setSize:` first for a quick solution, unless you also want multithreaded loading.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that.

Comment: Note: `GetIconRefFromFileInfo` is a deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

A Swift extension that lets you define your desired height (width) using Justin's solution

```
extension NSWorkspace {
    func icon(for url: URL, height: Int) -> NSImage {
        let image = icon(forFile: url.path)
        image.size = NSSize(width: height, height: height)
        return image
    }
}
```